# Binding data to a long list selector, C# WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've got a database and am looking to list all the items found into a longlist selector, it currently works, however the it doesn't display the actual text, just the object reference:

```
   //this will return all the records found in file table
        var query = context.Files;

        //now execute the query
        fileList = new ObservableCollection<FileTable>(query);

        //set up list items.
        llsEachItem.ItemsSource = fileList;
```

The longlist selector then just displays The object reference, for each item not the actual data itself. In this case it displays a list of:

```
Project.Model.FileTable
Project.Model.FileTable
Project.Model.FileTable
Project.Model.FileTable
Project.Model.FileTable
```

How can I make it so that I can actually see the data itself? I've tried appending toString() to the fileList but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the XAML code

Comment: Need more code like XAML and `FileTable` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **`DisplayMemberPath`** on list to the property name which you want to be shown in your list.

```
llsEachItem.ItemsSource = fileList;
llsEachItem.DisplayMemberPath = "PropertyName";
```